# Extract web links from iOS notes in app extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, ios-app-extension

I have an iOS share extension from which I want to import iOS notes into my application. All attachments can be obtained from the `extensionItem.attachments` property.

However, iOS 9 notes also support web links which can be opened in Safari. When I try to access a note containing weblinks, I only get `public.plain-text` as the registered type identifier for the extension item.

Also, using
`[extensionItem.userInfo valueForKey:NSExtensionItemAttributedContentTextKey]`
gives me an `_NSInlineData`, which when used to initialize `NSAttributedString`, does not specify `NSLinkAttribute`.
It also returns `NO` for `[NSAttributedString containsAttachmentsInRange:]`.

Is there any way to extract web links from the `NSExtensionContext`?

Comment: I don't use iOS App Extension, but could them be detected through `NSDataDetector`?

Comment: Thanks Larme.I tried using NSDataDetector but it doesnot return any matches for links